# Cloud Functions for Firebase: Reading the Entire Database into Memory

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I would like to read the entire Firebase database into a variable from inside a backend Cloud Function, as follows:

```
exports.transformUserData = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {

    admin.database().ref('/').on('value', function (snapshot) {

        var dbData = snapshot.val();
        ...

    });
    ...
});
```

1. Is this safe? (From a memory or dollar cost perspective, speed is not an issue in this case).
2. I expect the function will crash once my database grows due to an out-of-memory error. If this is the case, at what memory limit can we expect it to crash? (For example, [10MB](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/usage/limits)).

Thank you in advance for any advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is technically totally possible to read all data from your Firebase Database into memory.

As long as the hosting process has enough memory available this will work. If there is not enough memory, the script will crash.

It is impossible to say at what amount of memory this will crash, since this depends on the JSON data size, the data format (many small nodes will use more memory than one big node), and other factors.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you for your super quick response Frank! I also noticed that in your edit of my question you added a link which explains that 256MB is the maximum DB data extraction size. That is far more than I need! Supposing I only declare this single "dbData" variable, have a single user, and all else equal and simplifying: do you additionally know what the approximate maximum memory size that a variable can achieve in a Firebase Cloud Function is?

Comment: Cloud Functions run in a fairly standard Node.js. The maximum variable size will depends on Node.js itself and the [memory size of your Cloud Functions environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44500155/how-is-memory-allocated-to-a-google-cloud-function).

Comment: Perfect! Thank you! That link was very useful. Originally I had gone into this link but there was nothing there, but clicking around I selected my organization and found the project. The link (https://console.cloud.google.com/functions/list) showed that the function was by default allocated with 256MB of memory (you can increase it there as well to up to 2GB). I additionally ran tests and was able to allocate variables in the order of magnitude of 256MB as well (but never exceeding 256MB). All of my questions are resolved. Thank you again for the helpful information!