# Traversing large data set on firebase using cloud functions | Memory error

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to generate a report from some data in Firebase database and using Firebase cloud function for that purpose. As the data is quite huge, i'm getting memory error.

I think if i do pagination it will work. However, i'm not sure how to do pagination in Cloud functions. Is there a better approach to achieve this? **How can i perform pagination in Firebase cloud functions?**

My DB structure is something like

```
 {"threads" : {
    "228440-1704-4bba-87d7-27327" : {
      "messages" : {
        "8c98a76c-4456-4326-8e18-6d036b40bfa4" : {
          "is_failure" : 0,
         }, 
         "898376c-4456-4326-8e18-6deb4wr0bfa4" : {
          "is_failure" : 0,
         }
      },
      "recipients" : {
        "6036220" : {
          "group_type" : 2,
        }, 
        "7036220" : {
          "group_type" : 2,
        }
        }
    }
```

There are thousands of such nodes under "thread" node, and i can't get them by simply getting "threads" node. I need to calculate

1. total threads
2. total messages in all threads
3. total recipients in all threads

Right now, my code (without pagination) looks like the following, and it's giving memory error in Logs, hence not working:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.thread_node = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {

    var ref = admin.database().ref("/threads");
    return ref.once("value", function(threadSnapshot){
      var numberOfThreads = threadSnapshot.numChildren()
      var totalMessages = 0

      console.log("number of threads" + threadSnapshot.numChildren())

      threadSnapshot.forEach(function(threadSnapshot1) {

        var ref = threadSnapshot1.child("messages")
        var messagesPerThread = ref.numChildren()

        totalMessages = totalMessages + messagesPerThread
      })

      res.send(`
          <!doctype html>
          <html>
              <head>
              </head>
              <body>
                <p>numberOfThreads = ${numberOfThreads}</p>
              </body>
          </html>`
      );
   });
});
```

Comment: Try configuring your function to be able to use more memory.  You can use the Cloud console for that.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44500155/how-is-memory-allocated-to-a-google-cloud-function

Comment: @DougStevenson, thanks much. You saved my day..